# Quickly determine MPI datatype equivalence

Tags: mpi

When parsing an `MPI_Datatype` with `MPI_Type_get_contents`, one receives new handles for derived type(s) used to construct the outer one.

Because I'd like to reuse parsing results from a cache: How can I quickly determine if any of these handles matches another type I've already got a handle for?

I've already found that in MPICH I can potentially use `MPIR_Datatype_get_ptr` slash `MPIR_Getb_ptr` to query the underlying object and compare that pointer for equality and perhaps OpenMPI contains similar I can probe for during configure time. But if a more general approach works for any MPI I'd like to hear more about that.

I've searched for something like `MPI_Comm_compare` but for types no such function seems to exist. Also I had a look at keys, but it seems I'd need another notion of identity then?

Comment: I think `MPI_Type_get_envelope/get_contents` is all you have. Maybe you could compute a hash based on the results of these and use that? Otherwise I'm curious: just how much of a computational bottleneck is this comparison?

Comment: This is actually less about computational than programmer effort: if I haven't seen the component types, going further only makes limited sense for what I have in mind.

Comment: Current state: I keep an array with the original type handles and use that for comparing the types. Not pretty, but there seems to be no better alternative really. So I'd like a proper solution but having that extra array is not too expensive.